# Different MYSQL Output with same Query

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:

events:

```
id  |  name     
-------------------
1   |  Test
2   |  Another test
```

persons:

```
type            |  type_id  | name   |   user_id
------------------------------------------------
event_organizer |   318     |  NULL  |     22
event_owner     |   318     |  Rob   |     NULL 
event_owner     |   318     |  NULL  |     6
```

user:

```
id  |  forname  |  surname
--------------------------
6   |  Peter    |   Watson
7   |  Chris    |   Brown
22  |  Charlie  |   Teck
```

(Of course, the tables are much bigger than that, I just copied the relevant parts.)

This query:

```
SELECT event.*, 
  IF(persons.type='event_organizer', CONCAT_WS(', ', GROUP_CONCAT(forname, ' ', surname SEPARATOR ', '), GROUP_CONCAT(persons.name SEPARATOR ', ')), NULL) AS organizer_names, 
  IF(persons.type='event_owner', GROUP_CONCAT(forname, ' ', surname SEPARATOR ', '), NULL) AS owner_names 
FROM event 
LEFT JOIN persons ON persons.type_id = event.id AND (persons.type = 'event_owner' OR persons.type = 'event_organizer') 
LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = persons.user_id 
WHERE event.id=?
```

should output me all event data and the names of the owner and the organizer. The output I get is:

```
Array ( [id] => 318 [name] => Test [organizer_names] => Peter Watson, Rob, Charlie Teck [owner_names] => )
```

I don't get why `owner_names` is always empty. If I remove the `organizer_names` part:

```
SELECT event.*, 
  IF(persons.type='event_owner', GROUP_CONCAT(forname, ' ', surname SEPARATOR ', '), NULL) AS owner_names 
FROM event 
LEFT JOIN persons ON persons.type_id = event.id AND persons.type = 'event_owner' 
LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = persons.user_id 
WHERE event.id=?
```

Than I get the right owner (Rob and Peter Watson). I can also change it to:

```
SELECT event.*, 
  IF(persons.type='event_organizer', CONCAT_WS(', ', GROUP_CONCAT(forname, ' ', surname SEPARATOR ', '), GROUP_CONCAT(persons.name SEPARATOR ', ')), NULL) AS organizer_names, 
  IF(persons.type='event_owner', GROUP_CONCAT(forname, ' ', surname SEPARATOR ', '), NULL) AS owner_names 
FROM event 
LEFT JOIN persons ON persons.type_id = event.id AND persons.type = 'event_owner' 
LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = persons.user_id 
WHERE event.id=?
```

And this is working right too. So it seems that the second `OR` condition of the `LEFT JOIN` is destroying my owners :(

The reverse test (with same condition and without `organizer_names`):

```
SELECT event.*, 
  IF(persons.type='event_owner', GROUP_CONCAT(forname, ' ', surname SEPARATOR ', '), NULL) AS owner_names 
FROM event 
LEFT JOIN persons ON persons.type_id = event.id AND (persons.type = 'event_owner' OR persons.type = 'event_organizer') 
LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = persons.user_id 
WHERE event.id=?
```

brings also no `owner_names` output.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: I love MySQL for allowing aggregate functions without `GROUP BY` clauses, and the random output it then produces. Best database ever <3 [Read this article please, from beginning to end](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-5-7-only_full_group_by-improved-recognizing-functional-dependencies-enabled-by-default/). Especially the part about 'non-deterministic nonsensical queries'.

Comment: What would you change than?

Comment: Add an actualy `GROUP BY` clause as required by aggegrate functions.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I added a GROUP BY event.id. But it didn't change the output. What else does I have to group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `GROUP BY` aggregate functions without a `GROUP BY` clause **is** valid `SQL`. The standard says a single group is created from all the selected rows.

For this specific question, the appropriate `GROUP BY` clause would be `GROUP BY event.id`. However, it doesn't help because the `WHERE` clause already filters only the rows having a single value for `event.id`.

To debug the query remove all the aggregate functions in the `SELECT` clause and check that the correct rows are selected:

```
SELECT event.*, persons.*, users.*
FROM event 
LEFT JOIN persons ON persons.type_id = event.id AND (persons.type = 'event_owner' OR persons.type = 'event_organizer') 
LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = persons.user_id 
WHERE event.id=?
```

*Conceptually, this is the first step executed by `MySQL` when it runs your original query. In practice, some shortcuts are taken and optimizations are done and the result set you get is not generated completely; but this is how it works in theory.*

Most probably, the rows are correctly joined and filtered and the problem is in the way the values are aggregated.

Let's try to analyze how `MySQL` computes this expression:

```
IF(
    persons.type='event_owner', 
    GROUP_CONCAT(forname, ' ', surname SEPARATOR ', '),
    NULL
) AS owner_names
```

It uses all the rows selected by the query displayed above to compute a single value for the above expression. If you run the query you can see it produces rows that contain both `'event_owner'` and `'event_organizer'` in the `persons.type` column.

From the inside out, it uses all the values returned in the `forname` and `surname` columns to compute `GROUP_CONCAT(forname, ' ', surname SEPARATOR ', ')` then it uses one value from the `persons.type` column to check the `IF()` condition. But which one?

It is entitled to pick whatever value it wants for it from all the possible values of the `persons.type` column selected on the previous step. If, by chance, it uses `'event_owner'` it returns the value you expect and you think the query is correct. When it uses `'event_organizer'`, well, you are puzzled and ask on StackOverflow ;)

The correct expression of `owner_names` is:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(
  IF(                      # for each row
    persons.type='event_owner', 
    CONCAT(forname, ' ', surname),       # full name for owner
    NULL                                 # nothing for organizer
  )                        # owner name or NULL
  SEPARATOR ', '           # concatenate all using separator
) as owner_names
```

In a similar fashion you can compute the organizer names.

Comment: Thank you very much! (Answer and your corrections) My query: SELECT event.*, GROUP_CONCAT(IF(persons.type='event_owner', CONCAT(forname, ' ', surname), NULL) SEPARATOR ', ') as owner_names, GROUP_CONCAT(IF(persons.type='event_organizer', IF(persons.user_id IS NULL, persons.name, CONCAT(forname, ' ', surname)), NULL) SEPARATOR ', ') as organizer_names FROM event LEFT JOIN persons ON persons.type_id = event.id AND (persons.type = 'event_owner' OR persons.type = 'event_organizer') LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = persons.user_id WHERE event.id=?

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this - SQLFiddle appears broken right now - but I think you need to explicitly join organizers and owners as separate joins. Something like:

```
SELECT event.*, 
organizers.*,  
IF(organizers.type='event_organizer', CONCAT_WS(', ', GROUP_CONCAT(forname, ' ', surname SEPARATOR ', '), GROUP_CONCAT(persons.name SEPARATOR ', ')), NULL) AS organizer_names, 
owners.* ,
IF(owners.type='event_owner', GROUP_CONCAT(forname, ' ', surname SEPARATOR ', '), NULL) AS owner_names 
FROM event 
LEFT JOIN persons organizers ON organizers.type_id = event.id AND organizers.type = 'event_organizer'
left join persons owners on owners.type_id = event.id and owners.type = 'event_owner'
LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = owners.user_id 
left join user u2 on u2.id = organizers.user_id
WHERE event.id=?;
```

Comment: I had to give forname, surname and name the right table. Now I get the right names but they are all doubled -.- So f.e. organizer_names = {"Charlie Teck", "Charlie Teck"}